# Find the time it takes a body to travel $8$ meters in the curve $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, t)$ from $t=0$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

> Given the curve $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, t)$ and that a body starts moving from $t=0$, after how much time will the body travel the distance of $8$ meters?

It seems I need to use the definition of curve length:
$$
\int_a^b \sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2+(z'(t))^2}
$$

In my case I'm not sure if I'm choosing the right interval:
$$
\int_0^8 \sqrt{(-\sin^2t)^2+\cos^2t+1}=\int_0^8 \sqrt{2}=8\sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: That's the distance it travels in 8 seconds, not the number of seconds it takes to travel 8 metres. You should be taking something like $F(t) = \int_0^t (\cdots)$, and solving $F(t) = 8$.

Comment: They asked for time to travel 8m, not distance travelled in 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper limit is time dependent, you need to find a $t'$ such that,

$$\int_{0}^{t'} \|\gamma'(t)\| \ dt = 8$$

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the problem backwards.  Given a time $t_1$, the distance traveled between $t = 0$ and $t = t_1$ is given by 
$$
\int_0^{t_1} \|r'(t)\|\,dt = \sqrt{2} t_1
$$
What you're looking for is the time $t_1$ such that $8 = \sqrt{2} t_1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{t_0} \|\gamma'(t)\| \ dt = 8 \Leftrightarrow \int_0^{t_0} \sqrt{\sin^2t +\cos^2t +1} = 8 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2}t_0 = 8 \Leftrightarrow t_0 = 4\sqrt{2}$